# How do I set up Visual Studio Code to compile and run C code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I really like Microsoft's Visual Studio Code editor and I wonder how to configure it to compile and run C code.

Comment: In case you have not seen it: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Voting and accepting answers are always completely optional - but [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) as it provides code editing, navigation, and debugging support for C and C++ code.

Unless you are sure that you already have a compiler installed, make sure to install a C/C++ compiler and debugger and check the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) for more instructions!

> Popular C++ compilers are:
>
> - [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) on Linux
> - [Mingw-w64](http://www.mingw-w64.org/) on Windows
> - [Microsoft C++ compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019) on Windows
> - [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) for XCode on macOS

To run your code, and unless you want to go through the hassle of manual configuration, you can use [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

To run code:

> - use shortcut Ctrl+Alt+N
> - or press F1 and then select/type Run Code,
> - or right click the Text Editor and then click Run Code in editor    context menu
> - or click Run Code button in editor title menu
> - or click Run Code button in context menu of file explorer

To stop the running code:

> - use shortcut Ctrl+Alt+M
> - or press F1 and then select/type Stop Code Run
> - or right click the Output Channel and then click Stop Code Run in    context menu

You will also find more detailed instructions through the referenced links!